# APIs for videochatting

Tags: android, api, videochat

Can anybody recommend any APIs for integrating a live chat for android devices? Typically android to android devices. I want to use this for an android app project that I am currently working on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have asked 11 questions and accepted answers for none of them. Doing so will earn you reputation, and make it more likely you'll receive better answers in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SIP, and Also xmpp api extension of smack api.